# 2 spring boot projects inside one repository

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a repository on gitHub wehere i have a project already, the git structure is this:

```
master branch
   |-develop branch (first project)
          |-other sub branch of develop
```

Now, i need to add a second project (related to the first one) to the same repo but in another directory(?). I know that with intellij i can create a new module and when i push this module in the same repo, git will place it in another directory but in the same branch(?),
something like this :

```
-develope branch
 |-src first project
 |-gitIgnore first project
 |-pom.xml first project
 |-other files first project
 |-second project
```

But if i want the 2 project to stay in different branches?. Do i have to create a new develop branch for the second project and then pushit to the repo in the second branch? this way the 2 projects has indipendent branch history? Or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Possible misunderstanding of what a branch is. And of what Git is.

Comment: Possible, but i know what a branch is and what git is, i jus wrote what i saw  and what it seems like pushing a second project inside a repo.